# How send automatically email from excel tabs to different people with attachment

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I have 6 reports to send to multiple recipients or groups from excel tabs. 2 Report are weekly Monday, One is the other week of Monday, rest are 1st working day of the month. Each tab for each email subject and attach each tab in email. I need display/review them before send out to ensure accuracy. These tabs are updated weekly from my power query data source.

I tried woth one VBA to save those into separated excels in One drive. Then I tried another VBA to grab them and send email. But I want combine 2 VBA into one. That means send those tabs as separated sheets to dedicated email groups per my frequency.
I need CC my LM too in some email.